# Error with using ReplaceAll

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I wrote a For Loop. In this For Loop, I want to change the values of a list.  The main issue is:

I have a nested list like:

```
data={{{3941, 6870}, {3922, 6869}}, {{4022, 6869}, {4041, 6870}}, {{4066, 
   6869}, {4041, 6870}}, {{4097, 6868}, {4103, 6867}}, {{4103, 
   6867}, {4097, 6868}}}
```

I want to replace the first 2 (or 3) elements with other values

```
data /. data[[1 ;; 2]] ->  {{{3841, 6870}, {3822, 6869}}, {{3922, 
     6869}, {3941, 6870}}}
```

Unfortunalty, this ReplaceAll doesn't work, my output is:

```
{{{3941, 6870}, {3922, 6869}}, {{4022, 6869}, {4041, 6870}}, {{4066, 
   6869}, {4041, 6870}}, {{4097, 6868}, {4103, 6867}}, {{4103, 
   6867}, {4097, 6868}}}
```

Who can tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: I found a nice solution on: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244967/how-to-replace-a-list-array-of-variables-in-the-result?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

One way is not using ReplaceAll, but

```
data[[1 ;; 2]] = {{{3841, 6870}, {3822, 6869}}, {{3922, 6869}, {3941, 
6870}}}
```

which overwrites the first two elements. The remainder of the list remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{{3941, 6870}, {3922, 6869}}, {{4022, 6869}, {4041, 6870}}, {{4066, 
     6869}, {4041, 6870}}, {{4097, 6868}, {4103, 6867}}, {{4103, 6867}, {4097,
      6868}}};

new = {{{3841, 6870}, {3822, 6869}}, {{3922, 6869}, {3941, 6870}}};
```

Either

```
data2 = Join[new, data[[Length[new] + 1 ;;]]];
```

Or

```
data3 = ReplacePart[data, Thread[Range[Length[new]] -> new]];
```

The methods are equivalent

```
data2 === data3

(* True *)
```